# Flask : TypeError: _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Tags: python, web, flask

I've been working to todo app. What I' trying to do is when edit_todo method get todo_id as parameter, it gets relative data from database. Once user edit text and click submit button, it goes to update_todo method and update data in database. However, I got this error when I was working on edit and update text. I can't find which part goes wrong.

This is models.py

```
@app.route('/edit_todo/<int:todo_id>', methods=['GET'])
@login_required
def edit_todo(todo_id):
    if 'todo_id' is not None:
    g.todo = query_db('select * from todo where todo_id = ?', [todo_id])
    return render_template('edit_todo.html', todo_id=todo_id, todo=query_db('''
    select * from todo where todo_id = ?''',[todo_id]))


@app.route('/update_todo/<int:todo_id>', methods=['POST'])
@login_required
def update_todo(todo_id):
    if 'user_id' not in session:
       abort(401)
    if request.form['text']:
       g.db.execute('''update todo set text=?, pub_date=? where todo_id=?''', [todo_id],
                  request.form['text'], 
                  int(time.time()))
    g.db.commit()
    flash('Your todo was edited')
return redirect(url_for('index'))
```

This is edit_todo template

```
<form action="{{ url_for('update_todo', todo_id=todo.todo.id) }}" method=post>
<dl>
{{ todo.todo_id }}
  <dt>Todo:
  <dd><input type=text name=text size=60 value="{{ todo.text }}">
</dl>
<div class=actions><input type=submit value="Edit"></div>
</form>
```

This is part of the template where user can access to edit_todo template.

```
  {% for todo in todo %}
  <a href="{{ url_for('edit_todo', todo_id=todo.todo_id) }}" class="button">Edit</a>
```

Edit01: added error message

```
TypeError
TypeError: _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)

Traceback (most recent call last)
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1994, in __call__
            error = None
        ctx.auto_pop(error)

def __call__(self, environ, start_response):
    """Shortcut for :attr:`wsgi_app`."""
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)

def __repr__(self):
    return '<%s %r>' % (
        self.__class__.__name__,
        self.name,
File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1985, in wsgi_app
    try:
        try:
            response = self.full_dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            error = e
            response = self.handle_exception(e)
        return response(environ, start_response)
    finally:
        if self.should_ignore_error(error):
            error = None
        ctx.auto_pop(error)
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1540, in handle_exception
        # if we want to repropagate the exception, we can attempt to
        # raise it with the whole traceback in case we can do that
        # (the function was actually called from the except part)
        # otherwise, we just raise the error again
        if exc_value is e:
            reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
        else:
            raise e

    self.log_exception((exc_type, exc_value, tb))
    if handler is None:
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1982, in wsgi_app
    ctx = self.request_context(environ)
    ctx.push()
    error = None
    try:
        try:
            response = self.full_dispatch_request()
        except Exception as e:
            error = e
            response = self.handle_exception(e)
        return response(environ, start_response)
    finally:
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1614, in   full_dispatch_request
        request_started.send(self)
        rv = self.preprocess_request()
        if rv is None:
            rv = self.dispatch_request()
    except Exception as e:
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    return self.finalize_request(rv)

def finalize_request(self, rv, from_error_handler=False):
    """Given the return value from a view function this finalizes
    the request by converting it into a response and invoking the
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1517, in handle_user_exception
        return self.handle_http_exception(e)

    handler = self._find_error_handler(e)

    if handler is None:
        reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
    return handler(e)

def handle_exception(self, e):
    """Default exception handling that kicks in when an exception
    occurs that is not caught.  In debug mode the exception will
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1612, in full_dispatch_request
    self.try_trigger_before_first_request_functions()
    try:
        request_started.send(self)
        rv = self.preprocess_request()
        if rv is None:
Open an interactive python shell in this frame                rv = self.dispatch_request()
    except Exception as e:
        rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
    return self.finalize_request(rv)

def finalize_request(self, rv, from_error_handler=False):
 File "C:\Python27\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1598, in dispatch_request
    # request came with the OPTIONS method, reply automatically
    if getattr(rule, 'provide_automatic_options', False) \
       and req.method == 'OPTIONS':
        return self.make_default_options_response()
    # otherwise dispatch to the handler for that endpoint
    return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)

def full_dispatch_request(self):
    """Dispatches the request and on top of that performs request
    pre and postprocessing as well as HTTP exception catching and
    error handling.
TypeError: _wrapped_view() takes at least 1 argument (0 given)
The debugger caught an exception in your WSGI application. You can now look at the traceback which led to the error.
To switch between the interactive traceback and the plaintext one, you can click on the "Traceback" headline. From the text traceback you can also create a paste of it. For code execution mouse-over the frame you want to debug and click on the console icon on the right side.

 You can execute arbitrary Python code in the stack frames and there are some extra helpers available for introspection:

 dump() shows all variables in the frame
 dump(obj) dumps all that's known about the object
 Brought to you by DON'T PANIC, your friendly Werkzeug powered traceback interpreter.
```

Comment: Can you edit to include the full stack trace of the error?  It should give you the exact line where things went wrong.

Comment: @Roundel Hello, I added error message.

Comment: In edit_todo template `todo.todo.id` should be `todo.todo_id`, `action="{{ url_for('update_todo', todo_id=todo.todo_id) }}"`

Comment: @metmirr I changed it, but the result is the same.